# Elegant Way to Select Different Columns from Different Dataframe in R

Tags: r

I have two data frames as follows:

```
set.seed(123)

df1 <- data.frame(var1 = sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=500),
                 var2 = sample(c(0,1,99), replace=TRUE, size=500),
                 var3 = sample(c(0,1,2), replace=TRUE, size=500),
                 var4 = sample(c(0,1,3), replace=TRUE, size=500),
                 var5 = sample(c(0, 1, 2, 3), replace=TRUE, size=500))

df2 <- data.frame(var6 = sample(c(0,1,3), replace=TRUE, size=500),
                 var7 = sample(c(0,1,2), replace=TRUE, size=500),
                 var8 = sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=500),
                 var9 = sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=500),
                 var10 = sample(c(0, 1, 2, 3), replace=TRUE, size=500))
```

I want to `select` variables `var2`, `var6`, `var9`, `var4` and `var10` to a new data frame `df3`; here is what I did.

```
selected_df1 <- df1 |> dplyr::select(var2, var4)
selected_df2 <- df2 |> dplyr::select(var6, var9, var10)
df3 <- merge(selected_df1, selected_df1)
```

**What I Want**

How do I write `R` to use the `select` function in a statement using pipe operation `|>`?

**Edit**

I am thinking of this solution below. Can I get a more `elegant` solution?

```
df3 <- merge(df1, df2) |> dplyr::select(var2, var4, var6, var9, var10)
```

Comment: you have a one liner, how much more elegant do you want it to be?

Comment: don't include an answer as part of a question

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
cbind(df1, df2) |> subset(select=c('var2', 'var6', 'var9', 'var4', 'var10'))
```

or

```
cbind(df1, df2)[c('var2', 'var6', 'var9', 'var4', 'var10')]
```

or even

```
cbind(df1, df2)[paste0('var', c(2, 4, 6, 9, 10))]
```